# PHP code corrupting image file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am having a problem with a file uploading , i.E. my file uploads , but is not accessible i.e. I can't open the file in any photo viewer software. i believe my code is corrupting the file.

```
$(function(){

    $('button[type="submit"]').on('click' , function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('photo', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]); 


        $.ajax({
            url: 'fileupload.php',
            data: formData,
            // THIS MUST BE DONE FOR FILE UPLOADING
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            // ... Other options like success and etc
        });
    });
});
```

and the following PHP code.

```
<?php

$data = $_FILE['photo']['tmp_name'];

$serverFile = time();
$fp = fopen('uploads/'.$serverFile,'w'); //Prepends timestamp to prevent overwriting
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);
$returnData = array( "serverFile" => $serverFile );
echo json_encode($returnData);

?>
```

Can anybody tell me what am i doing wrong in the above code ?

Comment: `$data` contains the name of the file that you want to read from, not the actual data from the file?

Comment: @RyanVincent Thanks ryan , can you propose a solution !

Comment: See `move_uploaded_file()` for moving an uploaded file in php

Comment: the standard way of relocating uploaded files is with: [move_uploaded_file — Moves an uploaded file to a new location](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Comment: yes i know that trick using move_uploaded_file ! , I.E. u pass the temp path and the new path to upload to !

Comment: Did you do a debug to see what you are getting in $data?